# write as difference of two squares

Tags: algebra-precalculus

e.g. $x^2-4x = (x-2)^2 - 4$ write $3x^2 + 20x$ in the same way.

I have $3(x+10/3)^2 - 100/3$ but I am not sure if this is how they want it or if it is a difference of two squares

Answer (score 6):

$$3x^2+20x=(2x+10)^2-(x+10)^2$$

---

You can get this by comparing  $x(3x+20)$ with $$(ax+b)^2-(cx+d)^2=((a-c)x+b-d)((a+c)x+b+d).$$

So, in general, 
$$Ax^2+Bx=\left(\frac{A+1}{2}x+\frac B2\right)^2-\left(\frac{A-1}{2}x+\frac B2\right)^2.$$

Comment: pretty impressive that!

Answer (score 0):

You can have it as:

$$ 3\left(\left(x+\frac{10}{3}\right)^2- \left(\frac{10}{3}\right)^2\right)$$

$$\left(\sqrt{3}\left(x+\frac{10}{3}\right)\right)^2- \left(\frac{10\sqrt{3}}{3}\right)^2 $$

Or you can just go with mathlove's answer.